An anomaly in the NDBSI (Dryness Index) calculation when using Landsat 8
Today, my classmate encountered an issue while processing imagery, where the maximum and minimum values for the NDBSI index appeared to be abnormal. Specifically, when the data source was changed from Landsat 5 to either Landsat 8 or Landsat 9, there were extreme values in the hundreds or even thousands. According to his description, it's unlikely for NDBSI values to reach such high numbers. We discussed this for a long time but couldn't come up with a reasonable explanation. I'm wondering if anyone with relevant experience could provide a possible explanation for this phenomenon.
// landsat5 code
var roi1 = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/cloud-project-433203/assets/AUS/grid_37');
var roi = roi1.geometry();

Map.centerObject(roi, 8);

// apply ScaleFactors
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBands, null, true);
}

// remove cloud
function moveclouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
  var cloudMask = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3).eq(0).and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 4).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(cloudMask);
}

// function year
var startYear = 1990; 
var endYear = 1995;   

// cycle
for (var year = startYear; year <= endYear; year++) {
  var startDate = year + '-05-01';
  var endDate = year + '-06-30';

  // select year
  var L8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2')
             .filterBounds(roi)
             .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
             .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 60)
             .map(function(image) {
               return image.set('year', ee.Image(image).date().get('year'));
             })
             .map(moveclouds)
             .map(applyScaleFactors)

  var medianImage1 = L8.median().clip(roi);
  var medianImage = ee.ImageCollection([medianImage1]);

  var L8imgCol = medianImage.map(function(img) {

    // NDVI
    var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B4', 'SR_B3']);
    img = img.addBands(ndvi.rename('NDVI'));
    
    // IBI
    var ibi = img.expression('(2 * SWIR1 / (SWIR1 + NIR) - (NIR / (NIR + RED) + GREEN / (GREEN + SWIR1))) / (2 * SWIR1 / (SWIR1 + NIR) + (NIR / (NIR + RED) + GREEN / (GREEN + SWIR1)))', {
      'SWIR1': img.select('SR_B5'),
      'NIR': img.select('SR_B4'),
      'RED': img.select('SR_B3'),
      'GREEN': img.select('SR_B2')
    });
    img = img.addBands(ibi.rename('IBI'));

    // SI
    var si = img.expression('((SWIR1 + RED) - (NIR + BLUE)) / ((SWIR1 + RED) + (NIR + BLUE))', {
      'SWIR1': img.select('SR_B5'),
      'NIR': img.select('SR_B4'),
      'RED': img.select('SR_B3'),
      'BLUE': img.select('SR_B1')
    });
    img = img.addBands(si.rename('SI'));

    // NDBSI
    var ndbsi = (ibi.add(si)).divide(2);
    img = img.addBands(ndbsi.rename('NDBSI'))
    return img;
  });

  // select index
  var ndviBand = L8imgCol.first().select('NDVI');
  var ndbsiBand = L8imgCol.first().select('NDBSI');
  var ibiBand = L8imgCol.first().select('IBI');
  var siBand = L8imgCol.first().select('SI');

  // compute index max min
  var ndviStats = ndviBand.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });

  var ndbsiStats = ndbsiBand.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });

  var ibiStats = ibiBand.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });

  var siStats = siBand.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });

  // print
  print('NDVI Min and Max for year ' + year, ndviStats.get('NDVI_min'), ndviStats.get('NDVI_max'));
  print('NDBSI Min and Max for year ' + year, ndbsiStats.get('NDBSI_min'), ndbsiStats.get('NDBSI_max'));
  print('IBI Min and Max for year ' + year, ibiStats.get('IBI_min'), ibiStats.get('IBI_max'));
  print('SI Min and Max for year ' + year, siStats.get('SI_min'), siStats.get('SI_max'));

}


//landsat 8 compute code
var roi1 = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/cloud-project-433203/assets/AUS/grid_33');
var roi = roi1.geometry();

Map.centerObject(roi, 8);

// apply ScaleFactors
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBands, null, true);
}

// remove cloud
function moveclouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
  var cloudMask = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3).eq(0).and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 4).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(cloudMask);
}

// function years
var startYear = 2014;
var endYear = 2021;

// cycle
for (var year = startYear; year <= endYear; year++) {
  var startDate = year + '-11-01';
  var endDate = year + '-12-30';

  // select data
  var L8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
             .filterBounds(roi)
             .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
             .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 60)
             .map(function(image) {
               return image.set('year', ee.Image(image).date().get('year'));
             })
             .map(moveclouds)
             .map(applyScaleFactors)

  var medianImage1 = L8.median().clip(roi);
  var medianImage = ee.ImageCollection([medianImage1]);

  var L8imgCol = medianImage.map(function(img) {
    
    // NDVI
    var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5', 'SR_B4']);
    img = img.addBands(ndvi.rename('NDVI'));
    
    // IBI
    var ibi = img.expression('(2 * SWIR1 / (SWIR1 + NIR) - (NIR / (NIR + RED) + GREEN / (GREEN + SWIR1))) / (2 * SWIR1 / (SWIR1 + NIR) + (NIR / (NIR + RED) + GREEN / (GREEN + SWIR1)))', {
      'SWIR1': img.select('SR_B6'),
      'NIR': img.select('SR_B5'),
      'RED': img.select('SR_B4'),
      'GREEN': img.select('SR_B3')
    });
    img = img.addBands(ibi.rename('IBI'));
    
    // SI
    var si = img.expression('((SWIR1 + RED) - (NIR + BLUE)) / ((SWIR1 + RED) + (NIR + BLUE))', {
      'SWIR1': img.select('SR_B6'),
      'NIR': img.select('SR_B5'),
      'RED': img.select('SR_B4'),
      'BLUE': img.select('SR_B2')
    });
    img = img.addBands(si.rename('SI'));

    // NDBSI
    var ndbsi = (ibi.add(si)).divide(2);
    return img.addBands(ndbsi.rename('NDBSI'));
  });

  // select index
  var ndviBand = L8imgCol.first().select('NDVI');
  var ndbsiBand = L8imgCol.first().select('NDBSI');
  var ibiBand = L8imgCol.first().select('IBI');
  var siBand = L8imgCol.first().select('SI');

  // compute index max min
  var ndviStats = ndviBand.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });

  var ndbsiStats = ndbsiBand.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });

  var ibiStats = ibiBand.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });

  var siStats = siBand.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });

  // print
  print('NDVI Min and Max for year ' + year, ndviStats.get('NDVI_min'), ndviStats.get('NDVI_max'));
  print('NDBSI Min and Max for year ' + year, ndbsiStats.get('NDBSI_min'), ndbsiStats.get('NDBSI_max'));
  print('IBI Min and Max for year ' + year, ibiStats.get('IBI_min'), ibiStats.get('IBI_max'));
  print('SI Min and Max for year ' + year, siStats.get('SI_min'), siStats.get('SI_max'));
}


Any index that has a division in it could go large if divided by a small number. If the divisor is a difference then it will go large if the values in the divisor are nearly equal. Look at the locations where the NDBSI values are large and inspect the individual bands to see what is happening. Also, where's your definition and code for NDBSI coming from, it looks a lot more complex than https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S034181622200251X

Thank you very much for your reply. I will go and check it right away. This composite index is derived from the IBI and SI indices, where the IBI index was proposed by Xu Hanqiu, with the article DOI being: 10.1080/01431160802039957; the SI index comes from A. RIKIMARU's 'Tropical forest cover density mapping'. These two indices respectively reflect the properties of buildings and bare soil. We are attempting to see if this composite index can correspond to the aridity characteristic of the region. Currently, it is just a very preliminary attempt.
